# Windows 2008 server with Hyper-V and Vmware player

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware, hyper-v

Is there a way to install vmplayer on windows server 2008 r2 that has microsoft hyper v also setup. While trying to install I  get a message like

This product may not be installed as microsoft hyper v installed.

The server is running on cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may help you:

http://angledontech.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-install-vmware-player-after.html

You wont be able to run both hypervisors at the same time though.

Comment: Thank  you for the ink, unfortunately the win2008 is on cloud. I tried contacting their support. They said the win2008 as such is a virtual one on hyper-V hence there is not much that can be done.